# Webform is not submitting after 1st submit?

Tags: webforms

I am not able to submit a webform which is configured with honeypot.

I have tried following steps for anonymous user:

1. Place the webform using the webform block in a page.
2. Submit the webform. It got worked for 1st time.
3. When trying to submit from 2nd time onwards it is showing a message "There was a problem with your form submission. Please refresh the page and try again.".
4. After clearing cache only one submission is happening. From second submission onwards iit is not working.

Following are the module details:
Drupal: 9.1.x
Webform module:6.0.3
Honeypot: 2.0.1

There is no time restriction given in Honeypot module.

Comment: Any server-side caching layer?

Comment: @leymannx 

Caching is getting stored after every form submit.

Following code fixed the issue:

function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $advanced_validation = \Drupal::config('honeypot.settings')->get('advanced_validation');
  if ($advanced_validation) {
    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code helped to solve the issue.
Clearing the cache for every submission of a webform which is protected by honeypot.

```
    function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 
      $advanced_validation = \Drupal::config('honeypot.settings')->get('advanced_validation'); 
      if ($advanced_validation) { 
        $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0]; 
      } 
    }
```